# Best practice to save temporary data which should be reachable from different applications/processes

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ipc

I searching for a technique to save temporary data. It should be reachable from different .NET applications.

The data should exists about 60 seconds and i don't know if a database is the correct choice.

The reason: I want to manage user-tokens of webservices. And need a central application which manages the tokens and provide the functions GetNewToken() and CheckToken().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a case for an in-memory database / cache like [Redis](http://redis.io/), or [Memcache(d)](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/) (optionally can save to disk). You can save your data there using key with which it can be retrieved later and an expiration time.

For Redis you could use the [ServiceStack client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) written in C#.

Comment: Ok, but is such a in-memory database reachable from different threadsd without a server between them?

Comment: you can set redis/memcached up on the same machine as your .net applications, both mentioned are pretty light-weight, offer a TCP based API with client wrapper libraries and don't have any additional dependencies.

Comment: Also Redis is now an easy install in Nuget via http://nuget.org/packages/RedisIntegration

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered something like [MemCached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PlatformWindows) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the "other" .net application works I would suggest 1 of 2 things.

1. If the other service(s) always get the same data or data goes to specific services I would suggest using WCF services to pass the data around.
2. You could also use the MSMQ's

Answer (score 1):

A simple file could do the trick (XML file for instance).

A database could also fit, I would recommend for instance [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) here (database could be physically a single file on the disk).